# chrome console not opening my javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have been doing a prep course for telegraph academy and they provide us with html links that we open in a browser and use the javascript console to log our work. the only problem is my work never shows up when I open my console. I have saved all my sublime work files as javascript files and made the syntax for those files javascript as well. I also made sure that it is the exact same file name in my html file as my javascript files. I open chrome and its just a blank console. I can see the files in the source tab but I can't see them in the console tab. This was also the case with my work in the first week. It is week 2 and I still have this problem, but this is more of an issue because I am debugging this week so I need to have my console. Any advice helps

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this. But it usually happens when there is a bug in the js file. Since Javascript is interpreted, the execution simply stops when there is a bug. So, try setting up breakpoints in the js file, and debug them.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript console in chrome is purely for debugging. It will show errors, or script messages when they occur, but will not save anything or log requests.

You may want to contact the Academy you are with, and ask for clarification.